# SEO URL working for particular case only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a sign up page where the user can sign up. After signing up, they will be redirected to their profile. The redirection is: `example.com/profiles/?id=[SOME ID]`. After modifying the `.htaccess` file, I made it so that `example.com/profiles/?id=[SOME ID]` becomes `example.com/profiles/[SOME ID]`. This is my full `.htaccess` file:

```
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profiles/?\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profiles/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(?:profiles/)?([0-9]+)/?$ /profiles/?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Whenever I type in `example.com/profiles/48` it gets redirected to a 404 error, when it should exist. However, when I type in `example.com/profiles/index.php/48` it works and the user is redirected to their profile. How can I make it so that `index.php` is removed? So the URL will look like this: `example.com/profiles/48`

Comment: Is `profiles` a real directory or a file?

Comment: @OlafDietsche profiles is a directory. Inside profiles is index.php. index.php is the file that creates the dynamic page. So example.com/profiles/index.php is the real deal, but index.php is omitted from the url because of the rewrite method. When I go to a particular profile, say example.com/profiles/48, the profile is not shown, instead a 404 error is displayed